# Image download as wallpaper button for iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, ipad, mobile-safari, wallpaper

I am writing a wesite dedicated for iPhones and iPads.  On this website there will be a wallpaper for iDevices to download. But the standard procedure to save an image as a walpaper is quite long and annoying (long tap, save in photos, go to settings, change wallpaper). Is there any possibility to create a download button that just sets the wallpaper after one click? Maybe with jQuery or some specific Safari API.

greetings,
Jarek

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot change or set wallpaper programatically in iOS.